# Find highest value of aggregation and store in new column

Tags: mysql

I have a query to sum answers across some tables and now want to find out, which one has the most answers. This is my query:

```
SELECT Sum(surveys_answers.answer) AS Commitments
FROM   surveys 
       LEFT JOIN surveys_answers 
              ON surveys_answers.surveys_id_fk = surveys.surveys_id 
       LEFT JOIN surveys_times 
              ON surveys_answers.answer_time_id = surveys_times.times_id 
WHERE  surveys.surveys_id = 5132 
       AND surveys_answers.answer = 1 
GROUP  BY times_id 
ORDER  BY times_id
```

Since I just need the number of commitments this is the only column I've selected. But I also need to determine which row has the most commitments and want to add a new column "Highest" of type boolean to contain true for the row with the highest value.

I tried to use Max(Commitments) AS Highest, but it doesn't work. Is this possible without creating a Sub-Query?

Currently I get the following result:

```
+-------------+
| Commitments |
+-------------+
| 4           |
+-------------+
| 7           |
+-------------+
| 2           |
+-------------+
| 13          |
+-------------+
| 8           |
+-------------+
```

I want a result like this:

```
+-------------+---------+
| Commitments | Highest |
+-------------+---------+
| 4           | false   |
+-------------+---------+
| 7           | false   |
+-------------+---------+
| 2           | false   |
+-------------+---------+
| 13          | true    |
+-------------+---------+
| 8           | false   |
+-------------+---------+
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Is there a good reason you want to avoid a subquery? That's the way to do this kind of thing.

Comment: Nah, I just want to keep the query clean and readable. If this is still guaranteed with a subquery, there is no reason to avoid it.

Comment: I don't understand why you'd store this

Comment: Incidentally, contrary to appearances, your first join is an INNER JOIN.

Comment: To give the customer, what the customer wants.

Comment: Hmm. In SQL, unfortunately, "clean and readable" doesn't always mean "short and simple."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use a session variable trick here.  Define a row number session variable, and when it is equal to one it is the highest, otherwise not:

```
SET @rn = 0;

SELECT
    t.Commitments,
    CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END AS Highest
FROM
(
    SELECT
        t.times_id,
        t.Commitments,
        @rn:=@rn+1 AS rn
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
            times_id,
            SUM(surveys_answers.answer) AS Commitments
        FROM surveys
        LEFT JOIN surveys_answers 
            ON surveys_answers.surveys_id_fk = surveys.surveys_id 
        LEFT JOIN surveys_times 
            ON surveys_answers.answer_time_id = surveys_times.times_id 
        WHERE
            surveys.surveys_id = 5132 AND
            surveys_answers.answer = 1 
        GROUP BY times_id 
    ) t
    ORDER BY t.Commitments DESC
) t
ORDER BY t.times_id
```

Comment: Hi Tim and thanks for the reply. The query works but the column "Highest" is always false.

Comment: @Morph Apologies.  Please use this exactly: `SET @rn=0;` at the very beginning of the script.  My counting was off by one, this is why the query didn't work as expected.

Comment: No problem :) But now just the row gots Highest true. The Commitment of the row has the value 6 which is neither the highest nor the lowest value.

Comment: @Morph Please give my update one more shot.  I seem to recall that it's necessary to wrap the aggregation query before applying row number to it.

Comment: @Morph Note that my query does not handle ties.  If you want all ties for first, we would need to simulate the rank.  Not so hard, but a bit more work than this.

Comment: I tested the query with a few different surveys (so also different answers) and it workes as expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152641/discussion-between-morph-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: Hi again, got another issue related to this. I opened a chat, would be great if you find some time to discuss this quickly :) -> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152641/discussion-between-morph-and-tim-biegeleisen